# How to reset pip packages of python2 and python3 to the default in 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, python, python3, pip, python-2.7

I want to reset all the python modules in python3 and python2 to the default system packages in 16.04. I followed [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11250821/996366) `pip freeze | grep -v "^-e" | xargs pip uninstall -y` which broke my pip and pip3. I am able to reinstall pip using [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28919613/996366) but pip3 is still broken.

```
$ pip3 -V

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip3", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal import main
ImportError: No module named 'pip._internal'
```

How can I safely uninstall all the python2 and python3 modules to the system default?